# Problem getting contents of class using php simple dom parser

Tags: php, html, dom, parsing

I can't work out how to get the contents of the second span 'cantfindme' using php simple html dom parser(http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). Using the code below I can get the contents of the first span 'dontneedme'. I cant seem to get anything from second span at all.

```
$html =  str_get_html('<html><body><table><tr><td class="bar">bar</td><td><div class="foo"><span class="dontneedme">Hello</span></div></td></tr><tr><td class="bar">bar</td><td><div class="foo"><span class="cantfindme">Goodbye</span></div></td></tr></body></html>');
foreach($html->find('.foo', 0) as $article) 
{

    echo "++</br>";
    echo $article->plaintext;
    echo "--</br>";
}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you verify you need the content from both spans in the div element with class foo?

Comment: No I only need the second one but for some reason I can't select it using the class 'cantfindme'. There are also multiple 'cantfindme's in the document so it thought i would select it by using the foo  class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this selector.

```
$html->find('div.foo .cantfindme');
```

Check out the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you, that did it, you've been a great help.